# which logic should i use to fetch values to list from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have A xml file which will have data as  shown below:

```
<NAMES>
    <NAME name="a" Required="true" IsValidationRequired="true">
    <TASKS>
        <TASK name="add"/>
    </TASKS>
    </NAME>
    <NAME name="b" Required="false"  IsValidationRequired="true">
    <TASKS>
        <TASK name="102"/>
    </TASKS>
    </NAME >
</NAMES>
```

I need the output of the xml to  a `list` which will have the below values in one record

```
{
Name (attribute in NAME tag), 
Rquired (attribute in NAME tag),
isvalidationreq (attribute in NAME tag),
task (attribute in TASK tag)
}
```

so the List will have result like

> a,true,true,add
>
> b,false,true,102

Thanks

Comment: 1) You have incorrect closing tag for second `NAME` element 2) You have different elements for tasks - Task and TASK 3) Show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var names = from n in xdoc.Root.Elements("NAME")
            select new
            {
                Name = (string)n.Attribute("name"),
                IsRequired = (bool)n.Attribute("Required"),
                IsValidationRequired = (bool)n.Attribute("IsValidationRequired"),
                Tasks = n.Element("TASKS")
                         .Elements("TASK")
                         .Select(t => (string)t.Attribute("name"))
                         .ToList()
            };
```

Result:

```
[
  {
     Name: "a",
     IsRequired: true,
     IsValidationRequired: true,
     Tasks: []  // zero items, because there is element Task instead of TASK
  },
  {
    Name: "b",
    IsRequired: false,
    IsValidationRequired: true,
    Tasks: [ "102" ]
  }
]
```